# Groupby with both sum() and mean()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a bunch of data frames that I concatenate into one large data frame. All rows have a datetime, a name, and then some columns with random values, e.g. the data frame could look something like:

```
df =

ds                    name       val1     val2     val3
-------------------------------------------------------
2021-07-31 23:23:00   name1      2        3        4
2021-07-31 23:56:00   name2      3        4        5
2021-07-31 23:11:00   name1      4        5        6
2021-07-31 23:34:00   name2      5        6        7
```

I now need to group these rows by `name` and divide them into 60 min bins, which I currently do as follows:

```
final_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="60min", key="ds"), "name"]).mean()
```

And then the output is a new data frame where rows are grouped by `name` and then the `val` column value is just the mean of all values for that `name`.

And this works. However, what I would like to do is instead of taking the mean of all the columns, maybe the column `val2` should instead be the sum of the values - not the mean.

So basically the final output should be:

```
df_final =

ds                    name       val1     val2     val3
-------------------------------------------------------
2021-07-31 23:00:00   name1      3        7        5
2021-07-31 23:00:00   name2      4        10       6
```

Can this be done in any way, or would I have to split up my data frame into two, and then join afterwards ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataFrameGroupBy.agg` with a dictionary:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="60min", key="ds"), "name"]).agg({'val1': 'mean', 'val2': sum, 'val3': 'mean'})
```